# MS SQL : Need to get row wise value from cell for similar rows, Code not working correctly

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have 100s of excel sheets(CSV files) I need to use for the historical load. I am going to load all the CSVs to a stage table using ETL.

I am trying to get the row-wise value from the cell for similar rows. Please see the snapshot in the [link](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/0391sqxy97uw3rv/AADz6SPqCdJ1QO1j5Znf0C_Ka?dl=0).

```
Here is a sample creation of table script, else please refer to above link for full sample data

DROP TABLE #c
CREATE TABLE #C (col varchar(255) ,rowid int,col1 varchar(255))
INSERT INTO #C values('Wednesday, March 06, 2019 - Weather: TY: 15‹C', 1,NULL)
INSERT INTO #C values('a', 2,NULL)
INSERT INTO #C values('b', 3,NULL)
INSERT INTO #C values('c', 4,NULL)


INSERT INTO #C values('Thursday, March 07, 2019 - Weather: TY: 12‹C', 5,NULL)
INSERT INTO #C values('a', 6,NULL)
INSERT INTO #C values('b', 7,NULL)
INSERT INTO #C values('c', 8,NULL)

INSERT INTO #C values('Friday, March 08, 2019 - Weather: TY: 12‹C', 9,NULL)
INSERT INTO #C values('a', 10,NULL)
INSERT INTO #C values('b', 11,NULL)
INSERT INTO #C values('c', 12,NULL)
```

snapshot of the output here: black tick is correct, red crosses are wrong
[image]

I got the 1st three sections correct but others I got wrong. the red cross sections are wrong as I need to get the date in the row section.

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.[sql GET VALUES] ADD rowId INT IDENTITY(1, 1)
ALTER TABLE dbo.[sql GET VALUES] ADD RequiredColumn VARCHAR(255) NULL

UPDATE a
SET requiredColumn = column1
FROM dbo.[sql GET VALUES] a
WHERE column1 LIKE '%Sunday%'
      OR column1 LIKE '%Monday%'
      OR column1 LIKE '%tuesday%'
      OR column1 LIKE '%wednesday%'
      OR column1 LIKE '%thursday%'
      OR column1 LIKE '%friday%'
      OR column1 LIKE '%saturday%'

IF OBJECT_ID('Tempdb.dbo.#temptable') IS NOT NULL
BEGIN
    DROP TABLE tempdb.dbo.#temptable
END

SELECT rowID,
       CASE
           WHEN CONVERT(VARCHAR(255), requiredcolumn) IS NOT NULL THEN
               CONVERT(VARCHAR(255), requiredcolumn)
           ELSE
       (
           SELECT MAX(requiredcolumn)
           FROM dbo.[sql GET VALUES]
           WHERE rowID <= t.rowID - 1
       )
       END AS requiredcolumn
INTO #temptable
FROM dbo.[sql GET VALUES] t

UPDATE a
SET a.requiredcolumn = i.requiredcolumn
-- select a.requiredcolumn, i.requiredcolumn,* 
FROM #temptable i
    INNER JOIN dbo.[sql GET VALUES] a
        ON i.rowID = a.rowID

SELECT *
FROM [sql GET VALUES]
```

I need to get the date info to the row for each row with date value along the column.

Comment: Don't link to dropbox. Your link isnt working. Provide sample data and a minimal running example. Your question is not at all clear.

Comment: You'll find, as well, that people won't trust links to download resources from strangers. Put the DDL and DML in your post.

Comment: @CodeMonkey I am not quite sure how to explain my requirement, sorry if my post is not clear, please see attached screenshot and sample table creation script.

Comment: @Larnu I have edited with snapshots and sample table creation. The link is working for me in incognito mode, pretty sure it should work for everyone else.

Comment: @SuccessMaharjan Thanks for update i understand it now. I'll post a answer later today.

Comment: @SuccessMaharjan if you wan't to give it a stab yourself, the strategy would be to isolate each section(goolge sql gap&islands) then identify the row that keeps the correct date, just below the last NULL in column1. Its a bit involced due to the nature of the data but it can be done with a few assumptions.

Comment: Incognito Mode, Private Browsing, or not; I am not clicking a link to Drop Box from a stranger on a work/personal computer. And neither will many others.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using a CTE and a double use of the window function for MAX works for this.

And then it can be done in 1 update statement.

In the SQL, the first `MAX` calculates the highest previous/current Id with a valid column1 value.
The second `MAX` uses that calculated id to get the valid column1 value.

**Sample data:**

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#C', 'U') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #C; 
CREATE TABLE #C (rowid int primary key identity(1,1), column1 VARCHAR(255), RequiredColumn VARCHAR(255));

insert into #C (column1) values
('Wednesday, March 06, 2019 - Weather: TY: 15‹C'),
('a'),
('b'),
('c'),
('Thursday, March 07, 2019 - Weather: TY: 12‹C'),
('d'),
('e'),
('f'),
('Friday, March 08, 2019 - Weather: TY: 12‹C'),
('g'),
('h'),
('i');
```

**Update & select**

```
;WITH CTE AS
(
    select *, 
     max(case when rowid = MaxPrevId then column1 end) over (partition by MaxPrevId) as column1calc
    from
    (
        select rowid, column1, RequiredColumn,
        max(case 
            when column1 LIKE '%sunday%'
              OR column1 LIKE '%monday%'
              OR column1 LIKE '%tuesday%'
              OR column1 LIKE '%wednesday%'
              OR column1 LIKE '%thursday%'
              OR column1 LIKE '%friday%'
              OR column1 LIKE '%saturday%' 
            then rowid 
            end) over (order by rowid ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) as MaxPrevId
        from #C
    ) q
)
UPDATE CTE 
SET RequiredColumn = column1calc;

select rowid, RequiredColumn 
from #C
order by rowid;
```

**Returns:**

```
rowid   RequiredColumn
1       Wednesday, March 06, 2019 - Weather: TY: 15‹C
2       Wednesday, March 06, 2019 - Weather: TY: 15‹C
3       Wednesday, March 06, 2019 - Weather: TY: 15‹C
4       Wednesday, March 06, 2019 - Weather: TY: 15‹C
5       Thursday, March 07, 2019 - Weather: TY: 12‹C
6       Thursday, March 07, 2019 - Weather: TY: 12‹C
7       Thursday, March 07, 2019 - Weather: TY: 12‹C
8       Thursday, March 07, 2019 - Weather: TY: 12‹C
9       Friday, March 08, 2019 - Weather: TY: 12‹C
10      Friday, March 08, 2019 - Weather: TY: 12‹C
11      Friday, March 08, 2019 - Weather: TY: 12‹C
12      Friday, March 08, 2019 - Weather: TY: 12‹C
```

Comment: Hey @lukStorms, your code is working for me. Thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

Here try this, notice some assumptions about below code.

1. rowid starts at 1 at first row of first section.
2. Each section has same number of rows and is complete.
3. Each section has rows in the same order

If the above is not the case you need more columns to ID each section and distinguish rows within them. Ex. determin which rows within a section has a date or something like that.

```
--DROP TABLE #c
CREATE TABLE #C (col varchar(255) ,rowid int,col1 varchar(255))
INSERT INTO #C values('Wednesday, March 06, 2019 - Weather: TY: 15‹C', 1,NULL)
INSERT INTO #C values('a', 2,NULL)
INSERT INTO #C values('b', 3,NULL)
INSERT INTO #C values('c', 4,NULL)


INSERT INTO #C values('Thursday, March 07, 2019 - Weather: TY: 12‹C', 5,NULL)
INSERT INTO #C values('a', 6,NULL)
INSERT INTO #C values('b', 7,NULL)
INSERT INTO #C values('c', 8,NULL)

INSERT INTO #C values('Friday, March 08, 2019 - Weather: TY: 12‹C', 9,NULL)
INSERT INTO #C values('a', 10,NULL)
INSERT INTO #C values('b', 11,NULL)
INSERT INTO #C values('c', 12,NULL)




WITH InterSection AS
(
    SELECT *,
    (rowid - 1) % 4 AS SectionRowId,
    ((rowid - 1) % 4) - ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY rowid) AS SectionId
    FROM #C
)

SELECT c.*, ii.col AS NewCol1 FROM #C c
LEFT JOIN InterSection i ON c.rowid = i.rowid
LEFT JOIN InterSection ii ON ii.SectionRowId = 0 AND ii.SectionId = i.SectionId
```

Comment: Hey @codemonkey, the rows in sections are different in different dates.

Comment: @SuccessMaharjan Thats fair, then I would use LukStorms solution. Or you can extend mine and map op each row like he has done in his with a CASE WHEN LIKE pattern.